# Can I get data in object from double v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get dynamic table from this objects:

```
<tr v-for="product in allPosts" :key="product.id">
    <td v-for='(item, i) in checked' :key='`item${i}`'>{{product.item}}</td>
</tr>
```

So in this case "product" from first v-for and "item" from second. I want make it dynamic, but it's not working, just empty table. allPosts - big array of object with all data, checked - array user selected data. Elements in "item" are **equal** to keys in "product". Is it real?

allPosts (and 999 more lines like this):

```
[{"id":1,"post":"data","views":991,"comments":16,"likes":71}]
```

checked:

```
["post", "views", "comments", "likes"]
```

Comment: Please provide sample data for `allPosts` and `checked`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do it this way:

```
<tr v-for="product in allPosts" :key="product.id">
    <td v-for='(item, i) in checked' :key='`item${i}`'>{{product[item]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Notice the square brackets around `item`. This allows you to dynamically select the name of a property in the `product` object using the contents of the `item` variable.